# ihttphandler to write out file exactly as is

Tags: c#, asp.net, ihttphandler

I am writing a class that inherits from IHttpHandler for script and css combining. I only want to combine if the querystring has a special parameter defined. If this parameter is not defined then I want to write the contents of the file as if the handler wasn't even involved. What is the best way to deliver the file unharmed?

**EIDT:**

The one problem I'm encountering is that I have a script tag on the page that refers to a script in a virtual directory but the page I am on is in a subdirectory of the application.

The page that the control script is being referenced from is located at webserver/Admin/Default.aspx. When I access the Request object in the class that implements IHttpHandler all file path properties are the following: webserver/Admin/~/SharedScripts/control.js. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the query string parameter in the 'ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)' method like this:

```
context.Request.QueryString["paramertername"]
```

If you want to stream the requested file as is you can then do the following:

```
        string physicalFilePath = context.Request.PhysicalPath;
        string fileContent = string.Empty;

        // Determine whether file exists
        if (File.Exists(physicalFilePath))
        {
            // Read content from file
            using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText(physicalFilePath))
            {
                fileContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        context.Response.Output.Write(convertedFile);
        context.Response.Flush();
```

PS: You can also check out the following code project article for a more comprehensive example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/LocalizedScriptsAndStyles.aspx

Comment: The one problem I'm encountering is that I have a script tag on the page that refers to a script in a virtual directory but the page I am on is in a subdirectory of the application.

<script src="~/SharedScripts/control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

The page that the control script is being referenced from is located at http://webserver/Admin/Default.aspx. When I access the Request object in the class that implements IHttpHandler all file path properties are the following:
http://webserver/Admin/~/SharedScripts/control.js. How do I resolve this?